# Cartthrob, stripe and double payment

Tags: cartthrob, ecommerce, stripe

I've just inherited a site from a previous developer that is using CartThrob to power the eCommerce and strip/offline payments for the payment gateway.

Recently some customers have not been seeing the success notification template on submitting payment via stripe resulting in double payment submissions. One customer did not see the second payment go through and sent an email saying they would submit payment via check. However all payments are successfully received via stripe.

Is there a setting/template code that I need to work on to fix this issue? Any advice is appreciated.

EE 2.7.2
CT  Pro 2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to ensure the return template for order_complete is defined (and also exists). In the example below, the order_complete template should contain the [{exp:cartthrob:submitted_order_info}](http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/submitted_order_info/index.html) tag.

```
{exp:cartthrob:checkout_form
        return="{template_group}/order_complete"
        required="first_name|last_name|address|city|zip"
        gateway="stripe"
}
```

Stripe works differently than other CT gateways and some JavaScript implementation for error handling is required - so be sure to watch your console when testing.